# Error in creating bean userController caused by Could not create query for public abstract java.util.optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-repositories

Stack trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository.CustomJpaRepository.findFirst()!
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository.CustomJpaRepository.findFirst()!
No property findFirst found for type User!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional
br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository.CustomJpaRepository.findFirst()!
No property findFirst found for type User!

Classes:

- Controller:

```
package br.com.allen.flashfood.api.controller;

import br.com.allen.flashfood.api.assembler.UserModelAssembler;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.api.assembler.UserRequestDisassembler;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.api.model.request.PasswordRequest;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.api.model.request.UserPasswordRequest;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.api.model.request.UserRequest;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.api.model.response.UserResponse;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.model.User;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository.UserRepository;
import br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserModelAssembler userModelAssembler;

    @Autowired
    private UserRequestDisassembler userRequestDisassembler;

    @GetMapping
    public List<UserResponse> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> allUsers = userRepository.findAll();
        return userModelAssembler.toCollectionModel(allUsers);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public UserResponse getUserById(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        User user = userService.findUserOrElseThrow(userId);
        return userModelAssembler.toModel(user);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public UserResponse addUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserPasswordRequest userPasswordRequest) {
        User user = userRequestDisassembler.toDomainObject(userPasswordRequest);
        user = userService.saveUser(user);
        return userModelAssembler.toModel(user);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{userId}")
    public UserResponse updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId,
                                   @RequestBody @Valid UserRequest userRequest) {
        User actualUser = userService.findUserOrElseThrow(userId);
        userRequestDisassembler.copyToDomainObject(userRequest, actualUser);
        actualUser = userService.saveUser(actualUser);
        return userModelAssembler.toModel(actualUser);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{userId}/password")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void userPassword(@PathVariable Long userId,
                             @RequestBody @Valid PasswordRequest passwordRequest) {
        userService.changePassword(userId, passwordRequest.getActualPassword(), passwordRequest.getNewPassword());
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository;

import br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.model.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CustomJpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

CustomJpaRepository

```
package br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import java.util.Optional;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomJpaRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    Optional<T> findFirst();
}
```

User:

```
package br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime")
    private OffsetDateTime registrationDate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_group",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    private List<Family> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean passwordConfirmed(String password) {
        return getPassword().equals(password);
    }

    public boolean passwordNotConfirmed(String password) {
        return !passwordConfirmed(password);
    }
}
```

Edit 1:
I had forgotten to put the implementation in question because I thought it couldn't be that by editing the question now.

```java
package br.com.allen.flashfood.infrastructure.repository;

import br.com.allen.flashfood.domain.repository.CustomJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CustomJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomJpaRepository<T, ID> {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
                                   EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findFirst() {
        var jpql = "from " + getDomainClass().getName();
        T entity = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, getDomainClass())
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getSingleResult();
        return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `findFirst()` does not exist by itself.  You need to add more expressions to this, such as `findFirstByName(String name)`.  In other words, you won't be able to create a superclass with a `findFirst` method that can be properly inherited.  I don't really see a case here where I would create yet another interface to extend, you'll probably be better off just extending `JpaRepository` from your `UserRepository`.

Comment: Oh, the reason I am creating another interface is that in the future I will want to use the detach method which does not have in JpaRepository

Comment: You can pull this off, but you'll have to provide your own implementation as well since the implementations provide do not support this.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the help. I had forgotten to put the implementation in question because I thought it couldn't be that by editing the question now. But still gets the same error, I do not know if it can be some wrong annotation.

Comment: After your answers, I ended up encountering the problem, I forgot to use @EnableJpaRepositories to configure my implementation to be the base repository.